# Invalid value for field 'resource.sslCertificates[1]': ''. The URL is malformed

Tags: https, ssl-certificate, google-cloud-platform, load-balancing, google-compute-engine

I am getting this error while creating loadbalancing which I assume 
https giving error.
Do you have any idea how to fix, 
except getting another ssl certificate

thanks

Comment: What is the request you sent?

Comment: Did you specify 2 SSL certs with the 2nd one as empty string?

Comment: When I finalized load balancing error was coming. I deleted load balancing and will re-do. fingers crossed.

Answer (score 13):

This bug is still present in Google Cloud as of June, 2020. Here's how to fix it:

The problem is caused when creating a load balancer with a TLS certificate. Upon creating the load balancer, if you expand "Additional certificates", an additional dropdown appears that says "Select a certificate". You **must** delete the box by pressing the X on the right before selecting "Less".

[image: Creating a load balancer]

**Here is what it looks like expanded:**

[image: X out before proceeding]

**Make sure to "X" out all certificates that aren't set.**

Comment: thanks, that really did help. To be honest, its hard to even notice this.

Comment: Insane ! Crazy to get this kind of bug.

Comment: This bug is still present as of November 2021